# Make a call using UIWebView won't work in iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, ios6

In **iOS6** I am not able to make a call passing from `UIWebView`.

I use `UIWebView` because my app needs to come back after user close call, that is not possible using `UIApplication` method.

This the original code:

```
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://%@", escapedPhoneNumber];
_PhoneCallWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[_PhoneCallWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

Why iOS won't start a call?

#### NOTE: In all other iOS, starting from **3.1** to **<6** works correctly.

Using `[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:telURL]` it works but the app remain closed after call.

Comment: iOS 6 is still covered by an NDA, meaning that people who know about it probably won't answer here. Try the Apple dev forums.

Comment: Now that iOS 6 has been released, this is still a very valid issue. iOS 6 has affected UIWebView for my dev team and we're still trying to wade through the documentation to see what changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you should be routing phone calls through a `UIWebView`?

I have no experience with this type of thing but maybe you could try using the `NSURLConnection` class? It has an instance method `-initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` that might work in your case.

Comment: yes, if you try `[uiwebview loadRequest]` with tel:// it works and reopen back the app after call end.